# WordPress Post Date Changes On Update

Tags: datetime, wordpress, permalinks

I have my permalinks in WordPress set to the Month and Name setting. This generates URLs like /blog/2009/09/my-post-name. Every time a post is updated, it changes the posting date, which can potentially change the permalink address.

This is wreaking some havoc on my site, as I'll have banner/button ads throughout that point to the permalink. When a post from August is updated in September, all of the ads become broken links until I discover this and change it.

Is there any way to make the original posting date stay static, despite any updates? I'm looking for something like a plug-in or an overlooked setting, as I have multiple authors with varying degrees of computer literacy.

Thanks for any help!
Cory

Update:
Apparantly this is behaviour that others aren't experiencing, so I'm attaching a screen shot of exactly what's happening. Top image is before saving, bottom image is after saving.
[image]
<sub>(source: [opl.on.ca](http://www.opl.on.ca/assets/gfx/misc/wp-prob.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure updating a post changes the permalink? I don't have this behaviour in my installations. What do changes a permalink is changing the post date.

In database, acoording to [this schema](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), we have post__date and post__modified, two different attributes: used in create an update action. If you're having your post-date modified without modifying it directly

[Updating a post date in Wordpress http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3440/wordpresspostdate.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3440/wordpresspostdate.png)

then I'm afraid some plugin may be changing it's value.

Reading your description, I'm assuming you're using static links to your banners. Try to use a simple plugin that creates these links based on your post id: some simple routine would do it. You can get some information using [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) for example.

```
<?php
    $my_id = 7;
    $post_id_7 = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $slug = $post_id_7['post_name'];
?>
```

... or even easier with [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink). You need just your post id.

```
 <?php
    echo get_permalink(7);
 ?>
```

So, at least if your permalinks are changing without a reason and you dont know how to fix them, at least you can build them dinamically.

Just read the [codex documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org) and [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) to see what's avaiable to make your life easier!

Answer (score 1):

I run the same permalink settings and don't have trouble with post updates changing the permalink. There are separate editor settings for the permalink and a user has to specifically change the permalink from that editor, which is right under the post title in the text editing box in the post editor. That's a WP thing to keep permalinks from getting broken all the time.

Maybe you should try using a few static pages? That way you can have both a clean permalink: mysite.com/mypermalink/  that won't change, if in fact your post permalinks are changing from a plugin that you need to use.